# How to add "array of strings" as a schema value for BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I want to store an array of string values in a single column in BigQuery. In order to do that I need to first create a table with the proper schema. The schema identifier for the array is `ARRAY<T>` where `T` is the data type.

For example: `T` replaced by `INT64` as `ARRAY<INT64>` enables the storage of 64-bit integer array in that column. How should I get this same effect but for storing string values? I have already tried `STRING`, `VARCHAR` and `CHAR`.

Just mention: I am using latest `google-cloud` python package

[Documentation Reference for BigQuery Schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#declaring-an-array-type)

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44341234/does-google-bigquery-supports-arraystring?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In order to do that I need to first create a table with the proper schema.

just run below in Web UI with new destination table - to create needed schema

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT ARRAY<STRING>[] AS array_of_strings
```

Comment: It marks the mode as `repeated` rather than `nullable` which I was trying. But then the `google-cloud` package fails to upload array based data in BigQuery with the following error: `google.cloud.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Cannot load CSV data with a repeated field.`. Should this be opened as an issue on GitHub project repo?

Comment: if you want to store those string as an array - repeated is what you need - and this is how I originally read your question. but if you want just store each string as a separate row - this is different story (and much simpler one) . just clarify what result you expect. usually showing input and desired output helps in such cases

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The column will contain values which are similar to this: `['mobile', 'desktop']`. No need to store them as separate rows. Multiple values, as an array, in a single row+column.

Comment: and how your csv looks like? does it have `'mobile'` and `'desktop'` on different rows? or in one row?

Comment: Nope. Same row. Example row: `user1, ['mobile', 'desktop'], Canada`

Comment: in your mind  - is this supposed to be three column or four? :o)

Comment: haha Three columns. This is a sample data value hence it might seem non-intuitive to choose 3 vs 4 columns.

Comment: looks like you are doing simple load of csv into gbq table. and your csv has repeated data in it - which causes a problem for load. so, i would recommend first to load this csv as a one string column. the whole row is just one column. after data is in bigquery - you have much more flexibility to parse it then into final table with whatever schema is desired

Answer (score 23):

In order to add a column with array data, you need to define that column's mode as `REPEATED`. Hence a sample schema ends up being:

```
{
  'name': 'array_of_strings',
  'type': 'STRING',
  'mode': 'REPEATED'
},{
  'name': 'array_of_floats',
  'type': 'FLOAT',
  'mode': 'REPEATED'
}
```

This makes the field hold array values.

NOTE: You should be aware that if this is the schema of the table then you can not use CSV import functionality of big query since this is a limitation of CSV file format. You will need to use either `json` or `avro` formats.

[Reference to the GitHub issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3673)