# storing dense vectors in google bigquery table schema

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am creating a bigquery dataset to store dense vectors that represent users (generated from a machine learning algorithm). The vectors could have any length and will always contain float32's.

What is the smart way to structure my schema for this? This is what I have right now:

```
schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField('user_id', 'INTEGER', mode='REQUIRED'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('embeddings', 'record', mode='REPEATED', fields=[
        bigquery.SchemaField('embedding', 'record', mode='REPEATED', fields=[
            bigquery.SchemaField('index', 'INTEGER', mode='REQUIRED'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('value', 'FLOAT', mode='REQUIRED')
        ]),
        bigquery.SchemaField('timestamp', 'TIMESTAMP', mode='REQUIRED'),
    ]),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is here: [How to add "array of strings" as a schema value for BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315063/how-to-add-array-of-strings-as-a-schema-value-for-bigquery)

In my python code it looks like this:

```
schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField('user_id', 'INTEGER', mode='REQUIRED'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('embeddings', 'record', mode='REPEATED', fields=[
        bigquery.SchemaField('embedding', 'FLOAT', mode='REPEATED'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('timestamp', 'TIMESTAMP', mode='REQUIRED'),
    ]),
]
```